# Modify the voice of only two people to have a voice cast

Tags: voice-manipulation, dubbing

A little while ago, while watching a foreign and not-so-known (in my country) TV show, for a moment I lost focus and started thinking if it would be possible for only two people, a man and a woman, to record their voices for ALL characters (respecting the gender, of course) and modify them somehow (preferably with a reusable preset) to create a fully functional voice cast and actually dub the whole show.

I have absolutely zero knowledge on the matter but I had this curiosity with for afewdays already but I couldn't find much about it (probably because I'm using the wrong terms...)

In a positive case, could it be done by software only? If so, which one?

Comment: It's always better for the voice actor to change their own voice. There are techniques to accentuate the change. Having someone just talk normally, and modify that with effects will not give you good results. But a starting off point for it would be moving the formant up or down

Answer (score 1):

It is a common practice in video games to have one actor voicing several characters. For film and TV there shouldn't be an issue since actors are ussualy capable of voicing, though over-dubbing is another well used technique in post production.

Comment: Right,  so I wasn't that much wrong but, how exactly that would be done? Software, specific hardware... Like I said, no clue at all, just a huge curiosity XD

Comment: For voicing different characters, voice actors should have some good vocal and intonation skills as well any accent or language particularities that the script requires. In post production, there are certain edits that can be done to make the audio sound closer or further, add narration proprieties etc.

It mostly depends on what exactly needs to be conveyed.